# Disable password prompt when connecting to aws-ec2 with Fabric

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, fabric

When connecting with Fabric, I'm being prompted to enter a password, and when connecting manually I don't get anything - just being connected.

Do you know what can the issue be?

I am using ubuntu 16 based aws ec2 instance.
From my computer I'm running "fab test" for running the code below:

```
from fabric.api import *
import paramiko
paramiko.util.log_to_file("fab.log")
env.key_filename = '~/.ssh/etay-new.pem'
env.hosts = ['my.real-ip.trust.me']
env.user = 'ubuntu'

def test():
    run('ls');
```

I've checked the sshd_config and I do have ChallengeResponseAuthentication and PasswordAuthentication set as NO.

The fab.log:

```
DEB [20170518-00:12:30.497] thr=1   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0x558bbe50L
INF [20170518-00:12:30.742] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.2p2)
DEB [20170518-00:12:30.969] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex algos:['curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ssh-ed25519'] client encrypt:['chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com'] server encrypt:['chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com'] client mac:['umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1'] server mac:['umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
ERR [20170518-00:12:30.969] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Exception: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)
ERR [20170518-00:12:30.969] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Traceback (most recent call last):
ERR [20170518-00:12:30.969] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1585, in run
ERR [20170518-00:12:30.969] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     self._handler_table[ptype](self, m)
ERR [20170518-00:12:30.970] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1664, in _negotiate_keys
ERR [20170518-00:12:30.970] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     self._parse_kex_init(m)
ERR [20170518-00:12:30.970] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1779, in _parse_kex_init
ERR [20170518-00:12:30.970] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     raise SSHException('Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)')
ERR [20170518-00:12:30.970] thr=1   paramiko.transport: SSHException: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)
ERR [20170518-00:12:30.970] thr=1   paramiko.transport:
```

Any idea what to do? I don't want to be prompted to a password.

Thanks,
Etay

Comment: can you attach the output from fab.log?

Comment: Yes, I probably should have done it. I've added the original post and added it as it's too long for a comment.

Comment: can you make sure you are using latest version of parimiko? seems like ubuntu 16 may have updated a few parameters for SSH.

Comment: Well something went wrong while updating (???) so I had to reinstall python, fabric and pip (just to make sure), then sudo pip install paramiko --upgrade got me from 1.1 to 2.1 (using pip show paramiko) and it does work! Would approve you comment if I could :) Thanks!

Comment: I've added an answer to the question. Please mark as answered when you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update the `paramiko` version to latest 2.1.

Ubuntu 16 has an updated version of `sshd` which the `paramiko` 1.1 does not support.